# update() inside a function only searches the global environment?

Tags: r, function, environment

I tried to write a wrapper function to do likelihood ratio tests in batches. I tried to include update() to update the initial model. However, it seems that instead of looking for objects inside the function, it searches for objects in the global environment.

```
fake <- data.frame(subj= rep(1:5, 4), 
                   factor1 = rep(LETTERS[c(1,2,1,2)], each=5), 
                   factor2 = rep(letters[1:2], each=10), 
                   data=sort(rlnorm(20)))

foo <- function(){
                  temp <- fake
                  model1 <- lmer(data~factor1*factor2 + (1 |subj), temp)
                  model1a <- update(model1, ~.-factor1:factor2)
                  model1a}
```

And it gives an error message below:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'factor1' not found
```

Is there anyway to make update() search within the function? Thank you!

EDIT:

I made a mistake. I wanted to pass "temp" to lmer, not "fake".

EDIT2:
One convenient solution suggested is to simply specify the data object. Although update() now has no problem with this, anova() seems to think that the models I am trying to compare are based on different data objects

```
 foo <- function(){
                  temp <- fake
                  model1 <- lmer(data~factor1*factor2 + (1 |subj), data=temp)
                  model1a <- update(model1, ~.-factor1:factor2, data=temp)
                  anova(model1, model1a)
            }
 foo()
```

I get an error message:

```
 Error in anova(model1, model1b) : 
   all models must be fit to the same data object
```

I suppose this error goes beyond update(). But I wonder if anyone knows how this can be resolved. Note that if I write the function without using update() and instead spell out the models (see below), the error above goes away:

```
 foo <- function(){
                  temp <- fake
                  model1 <- lmer(data~factor1*factor2 + (1 |subj), data=temp)
                  model1a <- lmer(data~factor1 + factor2 + (1 |subj), data=temp)
                  anova(model1, model1a)
            }
 foo()

 Data: temp
 Models:
 model1a: data ~ factor1 + factor2 + (1 | subj)
 model1: data ~ factor1 * factor2 + (1 | subj)
         Df     AIC    BIC  logLik  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)  
 model1a  5 -4.6909 3.7535  7.3454                           
 model1   6 -8.8005 1.3327 10.4003 6.1097      1    0.01344 *
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

EDIT 3:
It seems that the issue is with anova(). I also tried the suggestion by @hadley

```
foo2 <- function(){
  my_update <- function(mod, formula = NULL, data = NULL) {
  call <- getCall(mod)
  if (is.null(call)) {
    stop("Model object does not support updating (no call)", call. = FALSE)
  }
  term <- terms(mod)
  if (is.null(term)) {
    stop("Model object does not support updating (no terms)", call. = FALSE)
  }
  if (!is.null(data)) call$data <- data
  if (!is.null(formula)) call$formula <- update.formula(call$formula, formula)
  env <- attr(term, ".Environment")
  eval(call, env, parent.frame())}

      model1 <- lmer(data~factor1*factor2 + (1 |subj), temp)
      model1a <- my_update(model1, ~.-factor1:factor2)
      anova(model1, model1a)
 }
 foo2()
```

I got an error message as shown below:

```
 Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
   cannot coerce class 'structure("mer", package = "lme4")' into a data.frame
```

Comment: works for me with no error in R 2.15.1, aside from needing to load lme4 package

Comment: Did you want to pass `temp` to `lmer` instead of `fake`?

Comment: Sorry, Yes, i wanted to pass temp to lmer, not fake

Comment: for what it's worth, this fails for me with the CRAN (stable) version of `lme4` (with `object 'temp' not found`), but succeeds with the development version (on github: https://github.com/lme4/lme4/ ).  There are some issues with stability of GLMMs in the development version, but otherwise as far as I know the development version dominates the stable version in terms of functions and robustness ...

Comment: Checking in on edit -- for what it's worth, the `anova()` example also seems to work with development lme4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been bitten by this behaviour before too, so I wrote my own version of `update`.  It evaluates everything in the environment of the formula, so it should be fairly robust.

```
my_update <- function(mod, formula = NULL, data = NULL) {
  call <- getCall(mod)
  if (is.null(call)) {
    stop("Model object does not support updating (no call)", call. = FALSE)
  }
  term <- terms(mod)
  if (is.null(term)) {
    stop("Model object does not support updating (no terms)", call. = FALSE)
  }

  if (!is.null(data)) call$data <- data
  if (!is.null(formula)) call$formula <- update.formula(call$formula, formula)
  env <- attr(term, ".Environment")

  eval(call, env, parent.frame())
}

library(nlme4)

fake <- data.frame(
  subj = rep(1:5, 4), 
  factor1 = rep(LETTERS[c(1,2,1,2)], each = 5), 
  factor2 = rep(letters[1:2], each = 10), 
  data = sort(rlnorm(20)))

foo <- function() {
  temp <- fake
  model1 <- lmer(data ~ factor1 * factor2 + (1 | subj), fake)
  model1a <- my_update(model1, ~ . - factor1:factor2)
  model1a
}
foo()
```

Comment: It seems that the problem now is with anova(). i tried your method, which works perfectly fine with model updating. However, when I tried using anova(), it gave me an error message as shown in EDIT 3 of my original post. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @AlexH., Hadley's answer is the way to go here. It passes the formula and data components in a way that will work with `anova`. In your `foo2` function above, you neglected to create the object `temp`, which, when added, worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Although I really like @Hadley's answer (and will likely use that function myself), you can also specify a `data` argument in the `update` function. (Here, I assumed you wanted to pass `temp` to your models.)

```
model1a <- update(model1, ~.-factor1:factor2, data = temp)
```

---

**EDIT**

If you're looking to compare models with `anova`, `update` will mung up the name of the `data` argument and "trick" `anova` into believing that the two models were fit using two different datasets. Updating only the formula and creating a new model will avoid this:

```
foo <- function(){
                  temp <- fake
                  model1 <- lmer(data~factor1*factor2 + (1 |subj), data=temp)
                  newForm <- update.formula(formula(model1), ~.-factor1:factor2)
                  model1a <- lmer(newForm, data=temp)
                  anova(model1, model1a)
            }
```

Comment: but ... I think this actually *doesn't* work with stable `lme4` (I agree that it should) ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker, Interesting issue. Before posting, I successfully tested the answer using R 2.15.2 on OSX with (I'm pretty sure) the regular CRAN Mac binary version of `lme4`. It also works with R 2.15.2 on WinXP using `lme4_0.999999-0` and `Matrix_1.0-9`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were doing.

Comment: It seems that anova() treats objects updated using update() as based on different datasets (see the example I added in my original post). Do you happen to a way to get around the issue? Thanks!