# Why is using update on a lm inside a grouped data.table losing its model data?

Tags: r, data.table, lm

Ok, this is a weird one.  I suspect this is a bug inside `data.table`, but it would be useful if anyone can explain why this is happening - what is `update` doing exactly?

I'm using the `list(list())` trick inside `data.table` to store fitted models.  When you create a sequence of `lm` objects each for different groupings, and then `update` those models, the model data for all models becomes that of the last grouping.  This seems like a reference is hanging around somewhere where a copy should have been made, but I can't find where and I can't reproduce this outside of `lm` and `update`.

**Concrete example:**

Starting with the iris data, first make the three species different sample sizes, then fit an `lm` model to each species, the update those models:

```
set.seed(3)
DT = data.table(iris)
DT = DT[rnorm(150) < 0.9]
fit = DT[, list(list(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length))),
          by = Species]
fit2 = fit[, list(list(update(V1[[1]], ~.-Sepal.Length))), by = Species]
```

The original data table has different numbers of each species

```
DT[,.N, by = Species]
#       Species  N
# 1:     setosa 41
# 2: versicolor 39
# 3:  virginica 42
```

And the first fit confirms thsi:

```
fit[, nobs(V1[[1]]), by = Species]
#       Species V1
# 1:     setosa 41
# 2: versicolor 39
# 3:  virginica 42
```

But the updated second fit is showing 42 for all models

```
fit2[, nobs(V1[[1]]), by = Species]
#       Species V1
# 1:     setosa 42
# 2: versicolor 42
# 3:  virginica 42
```

We can also look at the model attribute which contains the data used for fitting, and see that all the model are indeed using the final groups data.  The question is how has this happened?

```
head(fit$V1[[1]]$model)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7
head(fit$V1[[3]]$model)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 1          6.3         3.3          6.0
# 2          5.8         2.7          5.1
# 3          6.3         2.9          5.6
# 4          7.6         3.0          6.6
# 5          4.9         2.5          4.5
# 6          7.3         2.9          6.3
head(fit2$V1[[1]]$model)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 1          6.3         3.3          6.0
# 2          5.8         2.7          5.1
# 3          6.3         2.9          5.6
# 4          7.6         3.0          6.6
# 5          4.9         2.5          4.5
# 6          7.3         2.9          6.3
head(fit2$V1[[3]]$model)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length
# 1          6.3         3.3          6.0
# 2          5.8         2.7          5.1
# 3          6.3         2.9          5.6
# 4          7.6         3.0          6.6
# 5          4.9         2.5          4.5
# 6          7.3         2.9          6.3
```

Comment: This behavior can be recreated a little more simply with this: `m1 <- fit$V1[[2]]; m2 <- update(m1, .~.)`; `m1` and `m2` are then different.  Perhaps this will help in figuring it out.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying for ages to simplify this a little

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690184 - it may be related.

Comment: @hadley thanks - it definitely looks related.  If update is looking for the objects in the "global" scope then I wonder where it is looking when it is inside a `data.table`.  It is notable that it is NOT capturing the entire data.table column - only that of the final group.

Comment: I've had a detailed look but I'm baffled too. Have filed it as [bug#2590](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2590&group_id=240&atid=975) for now and will come back to it. Well spotted by the way, and great question layout.

Comment: @MatthewDowle -- I've detailed some findings in an answer of sorts. Not sure about a data.table side solution though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an answer, but is too long for a comment

The `.Environment` for the terms component is identical for each resulting model

```
e1 <- attr(fit[['V1']][[1]]$terms, '.Environment')
e2 <- attr(fit[['V1']][[2]]$terms, '.Environment')
e3 <- attr(fit[['V1']][[3]]$terms, '.Environment')
identical(e1,e2)
## TRUE
identical(e2, e3)
## TRUE
```

It appears that `data.table` is using the same *bit of memory* (my non-technical term) for 
each evaluation of `j` by group (which is efficient). However when `update` is called, it is using this to refit the model. This will contain the values from the last group.

So, if you fudge this, it will work

```
fit = DT[, { xx <-list2env(copy(.SD))

             mymodel <-lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length)
             attr(mymodel$terms, '.Environment') <- xx
             list(list(mymodel))}, by= 'Species']





lfit2 <- fit[, list(list(update(V1[[1]], ~.-Sepal.Width))), by = Species]
lfit2[,lapply(V1,nobs)]
V1 V2 V3
1: 41 39 42
# using your exact diagnostic coding.
lfit2[,nobs(V1[[1]]),by = Species]
      Species V1
1:     setosa 41
2: versicolor 39
3:  virginica 42
```

not a long term solution, but at least a workaround.