# How can I keep the entire lm objects returned from j argument evaluation in data.tables?

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose a data.table:

```
z = data.table(k=1:10, h=1:100, i=1:100)
setkey(z, k)
```

I want to estimate for each key k, lm(h~i).

My first thought was just to try:

```
result = z[,lm(h~i),by=key(z)]
```

But this returns an error, reminding me, 'All items in j=list(...) should be atomic vectors or lists.'

Next, following the error's suggestion:

```
result = z[,list(lmcol=lm(h~i)),by=key(z)]
```

But,

```
result[1,class(lmcol[[1]])]
```

returns 'numeric' instead of 'lm'!

What is the correct procedure for recovering the entire lm object from the second code block?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap everything in a list

```
result <- z[, list(lmcol = list(lm(h~i))), by = key(z)]
```

However, be warned that `update` etc don't work well with this approach see [Why is using update on a lm inside a grouped data.table losing its model data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096811/why-is-using-update-on-a-lm-inside-a-grouped-data-table-losing-its-model-data) for a description of this problem

Comment: Worked perfectly! For future possible visitors to this question, there's a small typo in your code block that may confuse people glancing over the question quickly. It should read `result <- z[,list(...),by=key(z)]`.

Comment: @user220419 - noted and fixed.