# Accessing linear models held in lists within a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm experimenting with data.table's ability to hold lists - in this case the output of linear models

```
require(data.table)

ir <- data.table(iris)
setkey(ir, Species)

lm.mods <- ir[, list(mods=list(lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width))), by="Species"]
```

I can access a single model

```
lm.mods[1 , summary(mods[[1]])]
```

But I can't work out how to create a new variable that is a list containing the summary of each model.  I think it may require `.SD` or `:=` but I can't work it out.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `lm.mods[, mods.sum := lapply(mods, summary)]; lm.mods$mods.sum`?

Comment: Beware of the pitfalls mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096811/why-is-using-update-on-a-lm-inside-a-grouped-data-table-losing-its-model-data/15376891#15376891

Comment: @Arun, that does the job - thanks. I was trying various combinations of lm.mods[, mods.sum := summary(mods)] which wasn't working.

Comment: @mnel, thank you - i'll bear that in mind