# Working with rich objects in data.table columns

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have a data.table in which one column contains linear models:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1014)

dt <- data.table(
  g = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  x = runif(7),
  y = runif(7)
)

models <- dt[, list(mod = list(lm(y ~ x, data = .SD))), by = g]
```

Now I want to extract the r-squared value from each model. Can I do
better than this?

```
models[, list(rsq = summary(mod[[1]])$r.squared), by = g]

##    g      rsq
## 1: 1 1.000000
## 2: 2 1.000000
## 3: 3 0.004452
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to eliminate the `[[1]]` and not rely on
knowing the previous grouping variable (I know I want each row to be
it's own group).

Comment: Maybe you should explain if there's a certain criteria you expect the `data.table` to have or why you need this? Given `models` and asking for `r.squared`, other than grouping by `g`, I can only think of using `lapply(...)` and then adding the result as a new column.

Comment: you could group by `1:nrow(models)` to avoid "knowing" about g

Comment: @arun If you know you're working with individual rows, you could internally use `[[` instead of `[`. That's what I'm thinking of for dplyr (with a special row wise grouper) and I was wondering if data table already had similar functionality.

Comment: Just because I don't know any better, why is using `[[1]]` worth avoiding?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor because in this case it's redundant

Answer (score 4):

This is just `summary` being a bad little function, that's not vectorized. So how about vectorizing it manually (this is roughly the same as @mnel's solution):

```
r.squared = Vectorize(function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)

models[, rsq := r.squared(mod)]
models
#   g  mod         rsq
#1: 1 <lm> 1.000000000
#2: 2 <lm> 1.000000000
#3: 3 <lm> 0.004451631
```

Comment: Most of the functions that work with linear models won't be vectorised, so that approach is a bit painful in general.

Comment: @hadley yeah, so you have to apply the function 1 by 1 yourself - how you choose to do it is up to you (explicit `*apply` or `Vectorize` or your original solution), but I don't see a way around that unfortunate fact

Answer (score 3):

My first thought was to use `rapply`, with `classes='lm'`, but that does not work. `sapply`, however does (to my surprise)

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1014)

dt <- data.table(
  g = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  x = runif(7),
  y = runif(7)
)

models <- dt[, list(mod = list(lm(y ~ x, data = .SD))), by = g]
models[, rsq := sapply(mod, function(x) summary(x)$r.squared)]

models
#     g  mod         rsq
#  1: 1 <lm> 1.000000000
#  2: 2 <lm> 1.000000000
#  3: 3 <lm> 0.004451631
```

"Doing other things" to the model within `data.table` might be problematic because of the way `.SD` works as environment.

See [Why is using update on a lm inside a grouped data.table losing its model data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096811/why-is-using-update-on-a-lm-inside-a-grouped-data-table-losing-its-model-data) for an example of what can occur. This is subject
of bug [#2590](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2590&group_id=240&atid=975).

Comment: using `lapply` make more sense here imo

Comment: @eddi - except that `lapply` will return a list, and thus transpose the response.

Comment: you're right, I got confused by how `data.table` outputs the two the same way

Answer (score 1):

Would that work?

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1014)

dt <- data.table(
  g = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  x = runif(7),
  y = runif(7)
)
models <- dt[, list(rsq = summary(lm(y ~ x))$r.squared), by = g]
#   g         rsq
#1: 1 1.000000000
#2: 2 1.000000000
#3: 3 0.004451631
```

Comment: No, because as well as extracting the r-squared from the model, I might want to do other things with them.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is inactive for more than two years but the solution already exists and is not described here.

```
require(purrr)
require(broom)
map_df(models$mod, glance)
```