# Apply grouped model group-wise

Tags: r, dplyr

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356683/apply-grouped-model-back-onto-data), but the problem I am facing has a twist that those answers do not address. Specifically, I am estimating a spatial model, `y=rho * lw * y + X *beta`. Because the observations are related by the matrix `lw`, I must apply the model to the entire `X` matrix simultaneously. Because those answers operate row-wise, they do not apply.

Here is MWE data, consisting of twenty points across three groups and a spatial weights matrix:

```
library(spdep)
#Coordinates
pointcoords <- data.frame(x = runif(n=20, min =10, max = 100), y = runif(n=20, min = 10, max = 100), ID = as.character(1:20))
pointsSP <- SpatialPoints(pointcoords[,1:2])
# Weights matrix
lw <- nb2listw(knn2nb(knearneigh(pointsSP, k = 4, RANN = FALSE), 
                      row.names = pointcoords$ID))

# Data
MyData <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:20, each = 3),
                     Group = rep(1:3, times = 20),
                     DV = rnorm(60),IV = rnorm(60))
```

I can estimate the models by `Group` with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
models <- MyData %>% group_by(Group) %>% 
  do(lm = lm(DV ~ IV, data = .), 
     sar = lagsarlm(DV ~ IV, data = ., listw = lw))
```

Predicting to new data with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376648/843419) operates on a row-wise basis, working fine for the `lm` objects,

```
MyData2 <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:20, each = 3),
                      Group = rep(1:3, times = 20),
                      IV = rnorm(60))

MyData2 %>% left_join(models) %>% rowwise %>%
  mutate(lmPred = predict(lm, newdata = list("IV" = IV))) %>% head()
#Joining by: "Group"
#Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
#Groups: 

#  ID Group         IV      lm        sar      lmPred
#1  1     1 -0.8930794 <S3:lm> <S3:sarlm> -0.21378814
#2  1     2 -1.6637963 <S3:lm> <S3:sarlm>  0.42547796
#3  1     3  0.5243841 <S3:lm> <S3:sarlm> -0.23372996
#4  2     1 -0.1956969 <S3:lm> <S3:sarlm> -0.20860280
#5  2     2  0.8149920 <S3:lm> <S3:sarlm>  0.14771431
#6  2     3 -0.3000439 <S3:lm> <S3:sarlm>  0.05082524
```

But not for the `sar` models:

```
MyData2 %>% left_join(models) %>% rowwise %>%
  mutate(sarPred = predict(sar, newdata = list("IV" = IV), listw=lw)) %>% head()
#Joining by: "Group"
#Error in if (nrow(newdata) != length(listw$neighbours)) stop("mismatch between newdata and spatial weights") : 
  argument is of length zero
```

I think there should be a better way of doing this, without joining the model to every row. Also, creating a list object for `newdata` won't work if you have several or changing predictor variables.  It seems that the `dplyr` way should be something like this:

```
MyData2 %>% group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(sarPred = predict(models$sar[[Group]],  newdata = ., listw=lw))
```

But the `[[Group]]` index isn't quite right.

Comment: Hm.  Does your first attempt work if you use `list("IV" = IV, listw=lw)` ? i.e. pass the weights *and* `"IV"` to the prediction function.

Comment: No, it gives an error, `spatial weights list required`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting this out there because it does do what I want it to, even if it needs to use a `for` loop (gasp)

```
predictobj <- list()
for(i in models$Group){
  predictobj[[i]] <- predict.sarlm(models$sar[[i]], 
                                   newdata = filter(MyData2, Group == i),
                                   listw = lw)
}
```

Anybody have a `dplyr` solution?

Comment: One advantage to this method is that it can be more easily parallelized, at least that I have found.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this with `do` in `dplyr`, going through the `models` data.frame rowwise.  I believe it does what you want, although the output doesn't contain the new data used for predictions.  I did add in `Group` to the output, though, as it seemed necessary to keep groups separated.

```
models %>%
    do(data.frame(Group = .$Group, 
                predlm = predict(.$lm, newdata = filter(MyData2, Group == .$Group)), 
                predsar = predict(.$sar, newdata = filter(MyData2, Group == .$Group) , listw = lw)))
```

**EDIT**

Playing around with adding the explanatory variable into the output data.frame.  The following works, although there is likely a better way to do this.

```
models %>%
    do(data.frame(Group = .$Group, IV = select(filter(MyData2, Group == .$Group), IV),
                predlm = predict(.$lm, newdata = filter(MyData2, Group == .$Group)), 
                predsar = predict(.$sar, newdata = filter(MyData2, Group == .$Group) , listw = lw)))
```

Comment: This is good, though I think it doesn't go through `models` *rowwise*, because `models` is a list. There will certainly be some post processing to get the data appended properly, but this works for now. I think this is a better answer for the other question, as well.

Comment: I don't have all the language from `dplyr` down pat, but the `models` object I'm working on appears to be a rowwise data.frame (`rowwise_df`).  I hadn't run into this term before, but I was originally attempting to group `models` and was warned `Grouping rowwise data frame strips rowwise nature`.