# loop lm predictions for plotting multiple lines

Tags: r, loops, subset, lm, predict

I want to plot linear-model-lines for each ID.

How can I create predictions for multiple `lms` (or `glms`) using sequences of different length? I tried:

```
#some fake data
res<-runif(60,1,20)
var<-runif(60,10,50)
ID<-rep(c("A","B","B","C","C","C"),10)
data<- data.frame(ID,res,var)

#lm
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(data,key="ID")
fits <- lapply(unique(data$ID),
function(z)lm(res~var, data=dt[J(z),], y=T))

#sequence for each ID of length var(ID)
mins<-matrix(with(data, tapply(var,ID,min)))
mins1<-mins[,1]
maxs<-matrix(with(data,tapply(var,ID,max)))
maxs1<-maxs[,1]
my_var<-list()
for(i in 1:3){
 my_var[[i]]<- seq(from=mins1[[i]],to=maxs1[[i]],by=1)
}

# predict on sequences
predslist<- list()
predslist[[i]] <- for(i in 1:3){
  dat<-fits[[i]]
  predict(dat,newdata= data.frame("var"= my_var,type= "response", se=TRUE))
}
```

predict results error

Comment: So where exactly are you stuck? The plotting part? What do you want the plot to look like exactly? I'm not sure I understand your desired output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356683/apply-grouped-model-back-onto-data/24356753#24356753 That was one of three hits to this SO search.

Comment: Further question: ???lms. I see no `lms` package in CRAN. Some sort of code omission must have occurred.

Comment: I am stuck at the last part of the script where I want to predict the models on the sequenses. The desired output is a plot with one line for each ID. The line shows the lm-predictions for ID[i] along the sequence[i] which has the range from min to max of var for ID[i]

Answer (score 1):

Plotting lm lines only for var[i] ranges works in ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
# create ID, x, y as coded by Matt
p <- qplot(x, y)
p + geom_smooth(aes(group=ID), method="lm", size=1, se=F)
```

Comment: nice! that's way easier.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're after?

```
# generating some fake data
ID <- rep(letters[1:4],each=10)
x <- rnorm(40,mean=5,sd=10)
y <- as.numeric(as.factor(ID))*x + rnorm(40)

# plotting in base R
plot(x, y, col=as.factor(ID), pch=16)

# calling lm() and adding lines
lmlist <- lapply(sort(unique(ID)), function(i) lm(y[ID==i]~x[ID==i]))
for(i in 1:length(lmlist)) abline(lmlist[[i]], col=i)
```

Don't know if the plotting part is where you're stuck, but the `abline()` function will draw a least-squares line if you pass in an object returned from `lm()`.

If you want the least-squares lines to begin & end with the min & max x values, here's a workaround.  It's not pretty, but seems to work.

```
plot(x, y, col=as.factor(ID), pch=16)
IDnum <- as.numeric(as.factor(ID))
for(i in 1:length(lmlist)) lines(x[IDnum==i], predict(lmlist[[i]]), col=i)
```

Comment: Thanks, nice short sript. But I get an error: Error: unexpected 'for' in:
"lmlist <- lapply(sort(unique(ID), function(i) lm(y[ID==i]~x[ID==i]))
                 for"

Comment: Sorry about that - was missing a parenthesis.  Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, great sript. The only thing which is not as desired is the length of the lines . They should span only over the range of x for ID[i].

Comment: Thanks a lot, perfect.