# fitting grouped regression model and extrapolating

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with the following columns: electricity consumption *E* (over 24 hours), hour *h* and temperature *t*.
I would like to extrapolate the consumption per hour for temperatures where I do not have data.

I have been following eddis's reply from [Apply grouped model back onto data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356683/apply-grouped-model-back-onto-data)

```
combinedprofiles <- data.table(df)

#Make a model for each hour
my.models <- combined_profiles[, list(Model = list(lm(E ~ t))),
                keyby = h] 

#Make predictions on dataset
setkey(combined_profiles, hour)
combined_profiles[my.models, prediction := predict(i.Model[[1]], .SD), by = .EACHI]
```

I have tried adding a dataframe with the new temperatures as new data to the prediction.

```
  newtemp<- data.frame(temp_round=c(6,7))
  combined_profiles[my.models, prediction := predict(newdata=newtemp,i.Model[[1]], .SD), by = .EACHI]
```

but this gives me the following error: Error in se.fit || interval != "none" : invalid 'x' type in 'x || y'

Could anyone please help me how to change this so as to predict demand for temperatures outside the measured data.

For the iris example my question would be, how to extrapolate Sepal.Length for data where we don't have Sepal.Width.

Thanks!

Comment: You are asking us to read too many of the neurons on your cerebral cortex.

Answer (score 0):

## Interpolating

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
```

`dplyr` to clarify `data.table` solution you want:

```
df <- as_tibble(iris)
df
#> # A tibble: 150 x 5
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
#> # ... with 140 more rows
```

We can just `mutate()` the fitted values

```
df %>%
  group_by(Species) %>% # for each Species
  mutate(
    pred = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width)$fitted.values
  )
#> # A tibble: 150 x 6
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  pred
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <dbl>
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa   5.06
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa   4.71
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa   4.85
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa   4.78
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa   5.12
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa   5.33
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa   4.99
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa   4.99
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa   4.64
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa   4.78
#> # ... with 140 more rows
```

### data.table

For this `df`, we can apply same logic.

```
setDT(df)[, pred := lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width)$fitted.values, by = Species]
```

1. define new column `pred` by `fitted values`
2. `by` each group `Species`

Then we get the same result:

```
df
#>      Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species     pred
#>   1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa 5.055715
#>   2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa 4.710470
#>   3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa 4.848568
#>   4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa 4.779519
#>   5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa 5.124764
#>  ---                                                                     
#> 146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica 6.611440
#> 147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica 6.160673
#> 148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica 6.611440
#> 149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica 6.972054
#> 150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica 6.611440
```

### Extrapolating

First of all, *the colname of `newdata` should be set same as the model*.

```
newtemp <- data.frame(Sepal.Width = c(6, 7))
```

As doing aggregation in `data.table`, you might do `.(predict(mod, newdata))`:

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)

dt[, .(pred = predict(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .SD), newdata = newtemp)), by = Species]
#>       Species      pred
#> 1:     setosa  6.781940
#> 2:     setosa  7.472429
#> 3: versicolor  8.730201
#> 4: versicolor  9.595279
#> 5:  virginica  9.316043
#> 6:  virginica 10.217578
```

---

If you want `newdata` column for each group, you can just add the term inside the list `.()`

I implemented `%>%` for readability.

```
df %>%
  data.table() %>%
  .[,
    .(newdata = unlist(newtemp, use.names = FALSE),
      pred = predict(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .SD), newdata = newtemp)),
    by = Species]
#>       Species newdata      pred
#> 1:     setosa       6  6.781940
#> 2:     setosa       7  7.472429
#> 3: versicolor       6  8.730201
#> 4: versicolor       7  9.595279
#> 5:  virginica       6  9.316043
#> 6:  virginica       7 10.217578
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Is there a way to add a column with the newdata to the prediction?

Comment: @maaar, Do you mean the `newdata` column?

Comment: I added the column. You can just write additional term inside `list()` of data.table. I think if we do not `unlist` your data.frame, it gets error.