# Updating a list of models with a list of data in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm working with multiple time series models, and hoping to manage them with data.table:

```
pkg <- c("data.table", "magrittr", "forecast")
sapply(pkg, library, character.only = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 10),
  val = sample(1:10, 30, replace = TRUE)
) %>% as.data.table
```

I can successfully generate the model (and a time series ready for the next step):

```
t1 <- df[, list(
  tsAll = list(val %>% as.ts),
  mod1 = list(val %>% as.ts %>% window(1, 7) %>% ets)
  ), by = group]
```

I'm now trying to update the ets model, which involves passing 'tsAll' into the ets function and providing the model to use (mod1).

This does not work:

```
t1[, lapply(tsAll, ets, model = mod1)]
```

I've also tried:

```
 t1[, lapply(tsAll, ets, model = mod1[[1]])]
```

This runs, but it looks like the same model is returned to every row.

Possibly I have solved the question but run into this issue:

[Why is using update on a lm inside a grouped data.table losing its model data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096811/why-is-using-update-on-a-lm-inside-a-grouped-data-table-losing-its-model-data/15376891#15376891)

Can anyone help with the next step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
t1[, list(lapply(tsAll, ets, model = mod1[[1]])), by = group]$V1
```

I put the result in a list, so that the data type is preserved, as opposed to being converted into a vector and did the operation by group (since each group has its own model).

Comment: That's it - so simple when you see it - thanks.  I've been getting an intermittent error where the first model is returned to all rows.  If I can pin down exactly what caused it I'll update the question.