# Any pitfalls to using programmatically constructed formulas?

Tags: r, scoping

I'm wanting to run through a long vector of potential explanatory variables, 
regressing a response variable on each in turn. Rather than paste together 
the model formula, I'm thinking of using `reformulate()`, 
[as demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967797/is-there-a-better-alternative-than-string-manipulation-to-programmatically-build/12967834#12967834).

The function `fun()` below seems to do the job, fitting the desired model. Notice, though, that 
it records in its call element the **name** of the constructed formula object
rather than its **value**.

```
## (1) Function using programmatically constructed formula
fun <- function(XX) {
    ff <- reformulate(response="mpg", termlabels=XX)
    lm(ff, data=mtcars)
}
fun(XX=c("cyl", "disp"))
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = ff, data = mtcars)                 <<<--- Note recorded call
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)          cyl         disp  
#    34.66099     -1.58728     -0.02058  

## (2) Result of directly specified formula (just for purposes of comparison)
lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, data=mtcars)
# 
# Call:
# lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp, data = mtcars)   <<<--- Note recorded call
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)          cyl         disp  
#    34.66099     -1.58728     -0.02058
```

**My question:** Is there any danger in this? Can this become a 
problem if, for instance, I want to later apply `update`, or `predict` or
some other function to the model fit object, (possibly from some other environment)?

A slightly more awkward alternative that does, nevertheless, get the recorded
call right is to use `eval(substitute())`. Is this in any way a generally safer construct?

```
fun2 <- function(XX) {
    ff <- reformulate(response="mpg", termlabels=XX)
    eval(substitute(lm(FF, data=mtcars), list(FF=ff)))
}
fun2(XX=c("cyl", "disp"))$call
## lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + disp, data = mtcars)
```

Comment: I think the issue will being careful using `update` see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690184/update-inside-a-function-only-searches-the-global-environment]. You can usually find out these pitfalls by trying to use `data.table` -- see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096811/why-is-using-update-on-a-lm-inside-a-grouped-data-table-losing-its-model-data/15376891#15376891]

Comment: This works: `do.call("lm", list(ff, quote(mtcars)))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck -- Thanks. That looks good, and seems like it shouldn't pose any problems down the road. (Also, thanks mnel for the interesting links.)

Comment: It is also worth looking how `add1.lm` works (using `. ~ .+` and `update.formula` and ti  to remember (or notice) that reformulate is just a wrapper for the paste method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm always hesitant to claim there are **no** situations in which something involving R environments and scoping might bite, but ... after some more exploration, **my first usage above does look safe**.

It turns out that the printed call is a bit of red herring.

The formula that *actually* gets used by other functions (and the one extracted by `formula()` and `as.formula()`) is the one stored in the `terms` element of the fit object, and *it* gets the actual formula right. (The `terms` element contains an object of class `"terms"`, which is just a `"formula"` with a bunch of attached attributes.)

To see that all of the proposals in my question and the associated comments store the same `"formula"` object (up to the associated environment), run the following.

```
## First the three approaches in my post
formula(fun(XX=c("cyl", "disp")))
# mpg ~ cyl + disp
# <environment: 0x026d2b7c>

formula(lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, data=mtcars))
# mpg ~ cyl + disp

formula(fun2(XX=c("cyl", "disp"))$call)
# mpg ~ cyl + disp
# <environment: 0x02c4ce2c>

## Then Gabor Grothendieck's idea
XX = c("cyl", "disp")
ff <- reformulate(response="mpg", termlabels=XX)
formula(do.call("lm", list(ff, quote(mtcars))))  
## mpg ~ cyl + disp
```

To confirm that `formula()` really is deriving its output from the `terms` element of the fit object, have a look at `stats:::formula.lm` and `stats:::formula.terms`.

Comment: Nice exploration.  I've used the `do.call` method previously because of some of these same questions.  It's nice to know these functions don't depend on the stored formula/call. However, I do believe that `update` does, so watch out for that usage.

Comment: @Aaron -- Thanks. Are you referring to the same issue as mnel did in the first comment following my question? If so, am I right in understanding that that pitfall would apply equally to *any* of the calls above? (i.e. using `do.call()` to launch the call to `lm()` doesn't help you avoid `update()`'s scoping issues, right?)

Comment: After further exploration, looks like `update` is safe too.  I was sure it wasn't though, but maybe I've been wrong all this time.  However, there are functions that do depend on the function being correct, for example, `anova.lme`; see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7666807/210673.

Comment: @Aaron -- Nice catch. By pointing me back to that question, I *think* you helped me locate and fix the bit of **nlme**'s code that caused the OP's call to `anova()` to fail. ([See my comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666807/anova-test-fails-on-lme-fits-created-with-pasted-formula/7667742#7667742) for more details.)