# How to extract the formula from a step regression?

Tags: r, regression

I'm running a step regression and I'd like to extract the final formula to use it in another regression.

Using this example:

```
lm1 <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss)
slm1 <- step(lm1)
```

I would expect to be able to assign this to a formula object:

```
Fertility ~ Agriculture + Education + Catholic + 
    Infant.Mortality
```

Comment: have a look at the call that is part of the `lm` object.  ie:  `slm1$call`

Comment: Thanks. The only thing missing is an `as.formula` function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply extract it from your `slm1` object using the `formula` method for `lm` object

```
formula(slm1)
Fertility ~ Agriculture + Education + Catholic + Infant.Mortality
```

Comment: @PLapointe You are welcome. In R there's always more than one way to do it... :)

Comment: @dickoa -- Yours isn't just another solution: it's the better one. [As discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17395724/any-pitfalls-to-using-programatically-constructed-formulas/17458699#17458699), the `call` element (used in P. Lapointe's answer) doesn't reliably capture the actually active formula.

Answer (score 4):

Got it:

```
> as.formula(slm1$call)
Fertility ~ Agriculture + Education + Catholic + Infant.Mortality
```