# Why does R `glm` function not work correctly when a string argument is passed for the formula at the same time that a subset is specified?

Tags: r, glm

The first two calls to `glm` work correctly, while the last one throws an error.

Why is this the case, and are there any known workarounds if I want to use a string for a formula, and specify a subset also? The use case is that I want to pass the formula as a string in my own function, without wrapping and unwrapping the raw formula.

```
library(ISLR)
foo =function() {
train=sample(10000, 5000, replace=F)
# both work
glm.fit = glm('default~income + balance', data=Default, family=binomial)
glm.fit = glm(default~income + balance, data=Default, family=binomial, subset=train)

# Does not work.
#glm.fit = glm('default~income + balance', data=Default, family=binomial, subset=train)
}
foo()
```

The error looks like this

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'train' not found              
Calls: foo ... eval -> model.frame -> model.frame.default -> eval -> eval  
Execution halted
```

**Update:** I have put the example inside a function because it seems to only be a problem inside a function.

Comment: I can't replicate this. `glm('default~income + balance', data=Default, family=binomial, subset=train)` works for me.

Comment: It appears that this only replicates inside a function. 
My original test code had the function, but I assumed that the function had nothing to do with it.
I will update my example.

Comment: In addition, note that when `train` is defined *outside* the function it works fine. It appears to look for the subset variable only in the global, not the local, scope.

Comment: My guess it is related to the issues discussed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690184/update-inside-a-function-only-searches-the-global-environment

Comment: Well, it appears that I can work around it by passing a closure which calls the  `glm` function with the appropriate argument instead.

Comment: Does anybody see where in the chain of calls triggered by `glm()` the character string supplied to `formula=` gets converted an object of  class `"formula"`?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Within `model.frame.default`. This uses the `environment` of the `formula` variable to search for the `subset` argument. The coercion from `'x~y'` compared with defining a formula object end up with different `environments`. (Not sure why the object can't be found further up (down?) the search path)

Comment: @mnel -- Thanks! I'm pretty certain that's the source of the problem. The environment of the call to `as.formula()` will be the evaluation frame of the call to `model.frame.default()` within which it is invoked, and it's *parent* environment will then be `package:stats` (the environment within which `model.frame.default` is defined). And then onto the base environment, the global environment, and on along the search path. The point being that, due to a combination of lexical scoping and the non-standard evaluation used by `glm()`, the data.frame passed to `data` will be completely missed.